# Knockout and JQuery UI custom binding no recoginizing widget on observable array update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

Hi All,

I am using Knockoutjs in conjuction with Jquery UI widgets to display a auto-complete box with multiple spans for each selected item.

I am following below approach

1) In the viewmodel have an observable array (selecteditems) and bind it to a declarative template to show SPANs

2) An input box bound to JQUERY UI autocomplete widget to show suggestions, and on each selection add a new item to the selecteditems array, using a CustomBindingHandler.

3) Use a CustomBindingHandler to show a JQUERY UI ToolTip widget to the each SPAN which are bound to observable array selecteditems.

Issue- that I am facing is JQUERY UI ToolTip widget is showing up in the load without any issues, but whenever there is a change in the selecteditems array, the Tooltip widget is not recognized in the CustomBindingHandler

Any help would be appreciated very much.

```
<div>

    <div style="max-height: 105px;" data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">

        <span data-bind="text: name, id: id, assignToolTip: id"></span>

        <input data-bind="assignAutoComplete: { rootVm: $root }" type="email" value="">
    </div>

</div>

<script>

    var MyViewModel = function () {
        this.selectedItems = ko.observableArray(
            [{ name: "eww", id: "ww" },
                { name: "aa", id: "vv" },
                { name: "xx", id: "zz" }]);
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.assignToolTip = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            if ($(element) != undefined) {
                var currentDataItem = ko.dataFor(element);
                $(element).tooltip({
                    items: 'span',
                    track: true,
                    content: function () {

                        return "<ul><li>" + currentDataItem.name + "</li><li>" + currentDataItem.id + "</li></ul>";
                    }
                });
            }
        },

    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.assignAutoComplete = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            if ($(element) != undefined) {
                var currentDataItem = ko.dataFor(element);
                $(element).autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            data: {
                                featureClass: "P",
                                style: "full",
                                maxRows: 12,
                                name_startsWith: request.term
                            },
                            success: function (data) {

                                response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                        value: item.name
                                    };
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        var settings = valueAccessor();
                        var rootVm = settings.rootVm;
                        rootVm.selectedItems.push({ name: ui.item.label, id: ui.item.label });
                        return false;
                    },
                    open: function () {
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };


    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the tooltip when a value in your array changes then you will need to change this around a bit so you can observe on the values of the object within your array.

```
var SelectedItem = function(obj){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(obj.name);
    self.id = ko.observable(obj.id);
    self.tooltipText = ko.computed(function(){
        return "<ul><li>" + self.name() + "</li><li>" + self.id() + "</li></ul>";
    });
    return self;
};

var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray(
        [new SelectedItem({ name: "eww", id: "ww" }),
            new SelectedItem({ name: "aa", id: "vv" }),
            new SelectedItem({ name: "xx", id: "zz" })]);
    return self;
};
```

Once that is complete you need to update the customBinding to handle updates:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.assignToolTip = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if ($(element) != undefined) {                
            var currentDataItem = ko.dataFor(element);
            $(element).tooltip({
                items: 'span',
                track: true,
                content: function () {
                    return currentDataItem.tooltipText();
                }
            });
        }
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext){            
        if ($(element) != undefined) {                
            $(element).tooltip( "destroy" );
            var currentDataItem = ko.dataFor(element);
            $(element).tooltip({
                items: 'span',
                track: true,
                content: function () {
                    return currentDataItem.tooltipText();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

The last change needed is that any time you push into the observable array it should be an instance of the `SelectedItem` object:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    var settings = valueAccessor();
    var rootVm = settings.rootVm;
    rootVm.selectedItems.push(
        new SelectedItem({ name: ui.item.label, id: ui.item.label })
    );
    return false;
},
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/PLYKk/

Comment: Why `if ($(element) != undefined)`? For one thing, using `if (element)` is shorter and does not involve a throw-away jQuery call, but even more important: `element` will simply never be undefined. *(Oh and on top of that, `$(anything)` will never be undefined to begin with, it will always be a jQuery object)*

Comment: @Tomalak I was not trying to code review the existing code. Certainly `if(element)` makes more sense however that was not the OP's question.

Comment: Oh I managed to overlook that this comes directly from the OP. Well, assume the comment was directed at him, then. :)

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation for the jQuery UI [Tooltip widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) suggests that the tooltip logic is intended to be bound to the container instead of to the individual elements.

For instance, to get a tooltip for all `<li>` in an `<ul>` in pure jQuery, you would do this:

```
$("ul").tooltip({
    items: "li",
    content: function () {
        return "tooltip text for this element";
    }
});
```

The main advantage is that you don't need to bind/unbind/update any tooltip logic when the container's children change. The other advantage is that this puts less load on the page because it registers only a single tooltip instead of several ones.

---

You can (and should!) use this approach because it fits your requirements perfectly. You have a container that has a variable number of children that should all show a tooltip with content built after the same logic.

Since we bind to the container, we need a tiny proxy function on the container's view model to retrieve the individual tooltip text for us.

The HTML template:

```html
<div data-bind="
    foreach: items, 
    tooltip: {items: 'label', content: tooltipContentProxy}
">
    <div>
        <label data-bind="text: name, attr: {for: id}"></label>
        <input data-bind="attr: {id: id}, value: inputVal, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

The `tooltip` custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).tooltip(options);
    }
};
```

Note how we

- can configure all the tooltip options conveniently in the binding
- don't have any dependencies on the view or the view model
- don't even need an `update` handler because this setup in decoupled from any data changes

---

And finally our view model:

```
function Item(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.inputVal = ko.observable(""); 
    self.tooltipText = ko.computed(function () {
        var escapedVal = $("<div>", {text: self.inputVal()}).html();
        return "Hi! My value is '" + escapedVal + "'.";
    });
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([/* Item objects here ...*/]);

    self.tooltipContentProxy = function () {
        var targetItem = ko.dataFor(this);
        return targetItem.tooltipText();
    };
}
```

Now tooltips show correctly without any further fuss. http://jsfiddle.net/7TqpK/